# Do you have to "initialize" (or something) an input file field after jQuery insertion?

Tags: jquery, forms, file-upload

I've got a Bootstrap modal that contains a form.  Leaving out a bunch of gory details, the form contains a button that, when clicked, creates and inserts an `<input type='file' ...>` field into the modal.  This works: the resulting widget appears properly on the page and is structurally correct, but doesn't actually work -- I can click the "Browse..." button, but the browser's file selection panel never appears.  This is happening in both Safari and Firefox.

Do I need to do some sort of initialization of the DOM or the field or the form or something to get things properly hooked up?  Very puzzled...

Comment: If you provide a demonstration of this behaviour I'm sure someone will look into it for you.

Comment: Did you also add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>` tag?

Comment: you'll need to tell us a little more.  what bootstrap framework?  do you know HOW the objects are being dynamically inserted?  a bit of code would be nice

Answer (score 0):

False alarm, it appears.  After some more head-beating, it turns out the field was getting put into not quite the right place, although why this got in the way of its working still isn't clear to me.  I've corrected it, and the file selection panel is now appearing and working like it should  Sorry and thanks to all.